# Sharepoint 2007 - full permission access

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We have a teamsite site collection with a number of subsites.

In the sub-sites. We usually break the inheritance and assign specific groups.

Now, our company director needs access to the all teamsites. We have over 100 teamsites. And it is difficult to assign him to each group for each teamsite. furthermore, we would have to remember to add him as a member to the teamsite each time.

Is there a way to add a specific Active directory user or group so that they can access all subsites (thereby overriding any break in the inheritance)

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Thanks,

Joseph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a web application policy.

If you head into SharePoint Central Administration --> Application Management --> Policy for Web Applications you should be able to set him up with the requisite permissions that will work across the sites within that web app.

For more information, have a look [here](http://glorix.blogspot.com/2007/10/policy-for-web-application.html)

(I've voted to have this moved to the SharePoint StackExchange site as it's not really Dev related)

Comment: Thanks! apologies for not posting in the correct forum - was not aware the other forum.